# Running end point from browser gives 503-Service unavailable

Tags: java, angular, httpclient, http-status-code-503

I am executing one of the endpoints which fetch data from database, and process data and display the output.

**Actual Problem**
when I enter URL in the browser, after 30sec(checked under Browser inspect -- Network -- Timing -- Waiting TTFB') it gives error on the page saying

There was an unexpected error (type=Service Unavailable, status=503).
No message available.

if I check logs, the request is still under process and it gives expected output after some point.

**My basic analysis** of this behavior is when I cut request shorter date range, and If I get the response before 30 sec then I could see the output in the browser.

Is this something to do with TTFB time.
I am really not sure and stuck with this.

I am happy to share more information if required to share your valuable suggestions!

[UPDATE] : Is it something to do with DB query performance, as browser is not getting response, in-spite of query execution is in progress in logs?

Comment: Do you use an HTTP accelerator like Varnish ?

Comment: @TechFree No,I dont use, should I use?

Comment: No, not sure but some property on your web server has a timeout of 30 secs

Comment: Maybe you can explain with more detail, all the pipe when the request enters in the backend?

Answer (score 0):

It was something wrong with DB query performance, as query was taking long time.
Which leads to more time(30sec) when I hit the end point in browser/postman.
I have optimised my DB query, and now the response comes in milli second.
Thanks !!